# Map of global sections is inclusion map

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, ringed-spaces

I have a question related to the answer to this question: [Morphism of ringed spaces not induced by homomorphism of rings](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2325274/morphism-of-ringed-spaces-not-induced-by-homomorphism-of-rings).

I understand the entire argument but I'm having trouble how I can see that the map of global sections $f^\#(\operatorname{Spec} A)$ is the natural inclusion.

Comment: It will help the reader if you make your question self-contained.